# AVPlayerViewController and UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, avplayerviewcontroller

In a storyboard, I dropped an AVPlayerViewController then display it by pushing on the navigation controller. It works great and displays my video. 
The problem is that when the user taps on the video controller to make the control disappear, the navigation bar stays visible. I'd like to be able to display it fullscreen without the navbar, but have not figured it out.
I can't see any method that would allow me to know the user tapped the controller

Any help appreciated.